# How get multiple choice in select

Tags: jquery, select, multiple-select

I have a drop down where user can select multiple options

I am trying to get all the options selected .I tried the following code snippet but does not seem to work.

can some one please help me on this

```
<select id="categorie" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple></select>
```

```js
$("select option:selected")
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, but `$('select').val()` will get you a comma delimited string with all the selected values.

Comment: Modified the problem statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get all the selected option values of multiple select drop down,you could do something like this

```js
$(function() {
  var optionsSelected = $('select').find('option');
  $("#click").on('click', function() {
    var selectedOptions = $('select').children('option:selected');
    selectedOptions.each(function(option) {
      console.log(selectedOptions[option].innerHTML);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="categorie" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple>

  <option>123</option>

  <option>12</option>

  <option>21</option>
  <option>14</option>

  <option>12</option>

  <option>121</option>

  <option>112</option>

  <option>201</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="click" value="click">
```

Hope it helps